# Is there a way to dynamically move a file from one device to another at the time of an SMB request?

Tags: network-shares, cache, smb

I am trying to figure out a way to move files on the fly from a traditional HDD to an SSD when a user requests a file via SMB

So the user would browse the server and when selecting the file it moves it to the SSD and allows the user to transfer/stream that file through the SSD for improved speed. It would be great if this could work the other way as well, writing directly to the SSD and then flushing to the HDD.

Thank you

Comment: What you’re describing is nothing more than caching. With that said, the initial request for the file will always be at the speed of the slower storage. You don’t provide any detail about your environment or use case, so the possibilities of hardware and software solutions are fairly endless.

Answer (score 0):

> So the user would browse the server and when selecting the file it moves it to the SSD and allows the user to transfer/stream that file through the SSD for improved speed.

This will only provide advantages for *repeated* requests. The first time the file is requested, it obviously still has to be read from the HDD, and it won't make much of a difference if it's streamed from HDD directly to network, or from HDD to SSD and from there to network...

That said, yes, there are various systems for doing this (depending on OS). They can be implemented at OS level (for both local and SMB access) or just by the network service.

Search for "SSD cache" or "tiered storage" (different things, but give similar results). For example:

- Linux has *bcache*, which works on partition level. (You have to reformat the HDD partition as a bcache device; live conversion is allegedly possible but I don't know if it works.)
- Windows Server has "Tiered Storage Spaces".
- ZFS apparently still has developers working on "persistent L2ARC". (Using an SSD as cache is already supported but it seems that it is reset on every boot.)
- Various larger NAS systems often have their own implementations.